# Как перевести некоторые заголовки в Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Такая проблема, есть интернет магазин на Вордпрессе (woocommerce), установлен шаблон, в настройках всё перевёл на рус. язык, но 4 элемента, которые есть на картинке *Shopping Cart*, *Product Categories*, *Products* и *Search Products* нет возможности перевести в настройках шаблона, а также и в настройках самого Вордпресса. Пробовал через исходники в Редакторе WP, но там стоит PHP-код с какими-то переменными. Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить ситуацию.

[image: изображение]

Comment: А может хотя бы немного приведете пример кода?

Comment: <!-- .four-columns - sidebar -->
<div class="sidebar four columns"><div class="widget-area clearfix "><aside id="woocommerce_widget_cart-2" class="widget woocommerce widget_shopping_cart"><h3>Shopping Cart</h3><div class="widget_shopping_cart_content"></div></aside><aside id="woocommerce_product_categories-2" class="widget woocommerce widget_product_categories"><h3>Product Categories</h3>

Comment: Нужно не картинки показывать, а указывать используемую тему (правильное название + ссылку на страницу в репо) и слова текстом которые нужно перевести.

Comment: @vladislav_zp Вам просто жизненно необходимо подучить принципы локализации в среде wp. Иначе просто сливайте таск на фриланс.

Comment: PHP-код с какими-то переменными - можно переменные в студию?
Обычно можно либо прямо в коде написать перевод, или (что более корректно) добавить перевод термина в локальный словарь.

Comment: @labris echo
if( mfn_sidebar_classes() ){

 echo '<div class="sidebar sidebar-1 four columns">';
  echo '<div class="widget-area clearfix '. mfn_opts_get('sidebar-lines') .'">';
   if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( $sidebar ) ) mfn_nosidebar();
  echo '</div>';
 echo '</div>';  ---------- вроде он

Comment: Проверьте, не задаются ли эти слова как заголовки виджетов в админке ВП. Если их там нет, и нет в коде темы - ищите в базе данных.

Answer (score 0):

У вас выводятся названия виджетов WooCommerce на английском.

Зайдите в админке на страницу Внешний Вид->Виджеты. Названия там. Так это выглядит в `BeTheme` на одном из моих сайтов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]